# Which is the best Maven2 plugin for Intellij?

Tags: maven-2, plugins, intellij-idea

What is the best Maven2 plugin for IntelliJ?  There are a lot of them now, and I don't have the time to play with them all.  It would be very helpful to get opinions and a feature synopsis on existing plugins.

Here is what I am looking for:  a) it keeps my paths and repositories synched to change in the pom file; and b) it doesn't keep hiding the target folder.

Also, I've found that an increasing number of archetypes are not parsable with my current setup.  Is there a plugin that provides better compatability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the default maven plugin available in the basic intelliJ installation.

---

**Resources :**

- [jetbrains.com - Ant and Maven](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html)

Comment: Thats the one that keeps concealing the /target folder :/

Comment: You just have to unhide it. Plus when there are directories int target containing generated sources, these directories are visible. Anyway, you won't find a better maven integration in IntelliJ than the IntelliJ's provided plugin. I you have ideas on how to make it better, the best thing to do is posting on intelliJ's forum or on the youtrack server.

Comment: actually, every time I compile the target folder is re-hidden